# Confusion about Java SE and Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, sdk, java

I am using Java SE with Eclipse happily but now I am going to write a "send mail" program which requires `javax.mail` package. I found that in Java EE so I downloaded one (180MB) and I know that Java EE installation needs SE JDK/JRE. Because I installed Java SE in `c:\java\jdk1.7` (not the default path) I use `-j c:\java\jdk1.7` to install Java EE. I have several questions about it.

1. How could I let Eclipse to load the Java EE package? Should I change the JRE in Java EE? Now Eclipse still only know the SE lib.
2. Do we have a JDK version which include APIs from Java EE? Because I really do not want to install two JREs in my computer and I do not need Glassfish. Can some one tell me which one I should download?
3. Is there `src.zip` for Java EE api? I cannot find it.

Comment: You don't need Java EE to use the Java Mail API, I quote *The JavaMail API is available as an optional package for use with Java SE platform* available from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html)

Comment: In any case, if you only need to write a send mail program, you don't need the whole Java EE monster. You can use Java SE and include both mail.jar and activation.jar into your classpath.

Comment: You're right that you don't need Glassfish for JavaMail, but that 180MB which you downloaded is basically Glassfish :) Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096/what-exactly-is-java-ee/7295697#7295697 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163374/netbeans-how-to-add-java-ee-container-to-java-project/12163715#12163715

Comment: You should probably use `maven` to avoid this category of headache. (And gain several new many more interesting categories of headache.)

Answer (score 3):

**Getting Java mail**

Download `Java Mail API` from [Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html).
Exctract the JARs (`mailapi.jar` has the desired `java.mail` package) and put in yout CLASSPATH by:

```
RightClick(project) -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries 
-> add Jars/Add External Jars (depends where you put your JARS)
```

**Updating the JRE**
In your eclipse, use the menu options as below:

```
    window -> preferences->  Java -> Installed JREs -> Add
```

Give the path as `c:\java\jdk1.7` and follow the steps to complete.
Once done, `JDK 1.7` will appear in the list with `checkbox` in front. Select the `checkbox` and press `OK`.

You should be all set, if you haven't done any project specific settings.

To verify the project specific settings, follow the steps:

```
    RightClick(project) -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries.
```

Your `JDK 1.7` should appear in right pane.

Comment: Hi Thanks I know how to set jre in Installed JREs. The problem is that c:\java\jdk1.7 is my java se path, the java ee is in c:\glassfish. Should I set the JRE in the glassfish to use java ee?

Comment: Please note that whilst this answers OP's concrete question, this way the OP is actually still going in the wrong direction as to achieving the concrete functional requirement of using JavaMail in a Java SE application.

Comment: Updated the answer with additional steps of getting JAVA Mail API.

Comment: @BalusC, what do you recommend he do then?

Comment: @oconnor0: just start reading the [JavaMail FAQ / developer guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html).